# Multiple select from checkboxes using c#

Tags: c#

Hy..I have a checkbox with 5 choices. I want to insert the checked values into one table separated by a ' , '.Here is my code:

```
        string str = string.Empty;

        foreach (ListItem item in this.checkbox1.Items)
       {
            if (item.Selected)
           {
                str = str + ",";
           }
        }

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["chestionar"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Raspunsuri Values('" + str + "',@cnp,@data,'10')", con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnp", Session["sesiune_cnp"]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());


        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("User11.aspx");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error:" + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

My problem is that when I hit the insert button it doesn't insert the values that the user checked.I must assign to string str a value.What is that value??

Comment: What do "checked values" represent? The indexes of the checkboxes (0,1,2..) ? Whether the boxes are checked (true,false,true...)? The text label of the checkboxes (Ham, Cheese, Peanut butter...)? What are you trying to save to the database?

Answer (score 3):

```
string str = string.Empty;

foreach (ListItem item in this.checkbox1.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        str = str + ",";
    }
}
```

The problem is that `str` never has a value so you are just writing a series of commas to the database - one for each item that's checked.

You need to append something else to the string to identify which options are selected - probably `item.Value`. So your code will become:

```
if (item.Selected)
{
    str += item.Value + ",";
}
```

However, using string concatenation like this isn't very efficient as it needs to recreate the string object every time (strings are immutable). So using `StringBuilder` will result in more efficient code.

Also is it OK that the the string ends with a comma? If not it's easy to remove:

```
str = str.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' })
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder();

if (item.Selected)  
{    
    if (sb.Length) > 0
        values.Append(","); // To ensure that the last char is not a comma after the loop
    values.Append(item.value);

}  


SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Raspunsuri Values(@str,@cnp,@data,'10')", con);
```

Add:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@str", values.ToString());
```

1. So we remove the sql injection you could possible get by passing the values as a parameter. Also, to get the selected value of a ListItem you use the Value property.
2. Now all you do is add the value to a stringbuilder (you don't need to use a stringbuilder but it's more efficient if there are a lot of values in the listbox).
3. Set the parameter's value from the StringBuilder

Comment: Thanks guys..this was very helpful but now I am getting the comma like this:  ,option1,option2..

Comment: Are you sure you added the lines: if (sb.Length) > 0 values.Append(","); What this essentially does is if there is another value to be added, it checks if there are any values added first, if there is then it means it needs a comma, if there isn't it means there should not be a comma as this is the first value.

Answer (score 0):

- First: avoid concatenation of `string` in the loop. Strings in `C#` are immutable so you allocate a new memory on every iteration. Use `StringBuilder()` and its `Append()` method for that.
- Never, ever write directly string into the `SQL`. **ALways** use a parameters. So your code has to be looked like this:

  ```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Raspunsuri   Values (@stringvalue,@cnp,@data, @tenvalue)", con);

  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stringvalue", str);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnp", Session["sesiune_cnp"]);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
  ```

I think, by resolving this you will resolve your problem too.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MultipleCheckBoxesApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string _concateString = "";
        private void checkBoxButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> ourList = new List<string>();
            if (csharpCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                ourList.Add(csharpCheckBox.Text);
            }
            if (javaCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                ourList.Add(javaCheckBox.Text);
            }
            if (cCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                ourList.Add(cCheckBox.Text);
            }
            if (phpCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                ourList.Add(phpCheckBox.Text);
            }
            if (cplusCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                ourList.Add(cplusCheckBox.Text);
            }
            foreach (string checkList in ourList)
            {
                _concateString += checkList + " ,";
            }
            if (_concateString == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nothing Checked", "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(_concateString + " has been checked");
            }

            ourList.Clear();
            _concateString = string.Empty;



        }
    }
}
```